# Flutter WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() appears when dealing with rootBundle inside an isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

In my Flutter app, there is a heavy task that forces me to use isolates in order to have a smooth UI, and that task includes reading some assets files using the rootBundle and searching through them for a certain text. Now since the main isolate that renders the UI doesn't share memory with the spawned isolate that will do the heavy task for me, whenever I try to use the rootBundle inside the method which the spawned isolate runs, I get this error:

> ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding
> was initialized.

And of course using **WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();** at the top of the method doesn't work.
And I tried to send the rootBundle to the spawned Isolate and using it there but that didn't work.

Comment: *"And of course using WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); at the top of the method doesn't work"* - what method? `Isolate`'s entry point (i mean the first param of `Isolate.spawn()`)?

Comment: @pskink the reference of the method that will be executed and I takes a SendPort parameter, I even tried to send the rootBundle to the spawned Isolate and still got the same eror

Comment: @pskink yes I've tried too and got the same error and that's why I said "using WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); at the top of the method doesn't work."

Comment: so it seems you need to read your assets in the main isolate

Comment: @pskink yes, that's what I've done and after done reading, I spawned an isolate to search among the data that was already read by the main isolate.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this to flutter devs: [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61480](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/services/isolate.dart)

They responded saying that this is not a bug, maybe it is as-is. Checking the flutters samples you can find this:

```
// Load the JSON string. This is done in the main isolate because spawned
// isolates do not have access to the root bundle. However, the loading
// process is asynchronous, so the UI will not block while the file is
// loaded.
```

The full example file:

> [Blockquote](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/services/isolate.dart)